# pip: inconsistent permissions issues

Tags: python, centos, pip, python-module

When installing a package via `sudo pip-python` (CentOS 6 package: `python-pip-0.8-1.el6.noarch`), I sometimes get permission issues with the installed packages being readable only by root.

Re-installing again one or two times usually fixes the problem. Has anyone experienced this? Or can anyone suggest any troubleshooting steps to nail down the cause?

Answer (score 14):

When you run a command using `sudo`, it will preserve the users `umask`. `pip` just installs files, it doesn't change access rights, so you'll end up with the files having the access rights set conforming to the current user's umask, which may be owner-readable only (0077) and therefore readable by root only.

That means you can set umask to something sensible like `umask 0022` before running `sudo pip install`. Or use `sudo su` to open a root shell with default settings and then `pip install`.

Comment: Initially, when one of our staff members reported this, I thought the same thing. However, it has now happened to me a couple of times where it sets restrictive permissions first but then, when I run it again without changing anything, it works fine.

Comment: Hm, that really seems strange, specially the 'without changin anything' part. I've only seen this problem when running pip through sudo, now I always run pip from the root shell with a proper umask, an it hasn't happened to me since. Don't know what's going on here...

Comment: You can also run sudo bash, then umask 0022, then pip install

Comment: Great tip, thanks.  
After installation I changed permissions:

cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages; chmod -R o+rw *

and everything worked fine

Comment: @artejera that's a very bad idea as it opens a big security vulnerability. Now anybody can place or modify files there, and compromise any other use of these packages. Nothing below /usr should be world writeable!

Answer (score 0):

If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag

-H, --set-home              set HOME variable to target user's home dir

e.g

`sudo -H pip install virtualenv`