# How to install a module for all users with pip on linux?

Tags: python, linux, pip, sudo

How to install a package in the standard python environment *i.e.* `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` using `pip` and make this new package available for all the users without using `virtualenv`?

By using the following, the package is installed with root permissions only:

```
$ sudo pip install loremipsum
Downloading/unpacking loremipsum
  Downloading loremipsum-1.0.5.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/loremipsum/setup.py) 
  egg_info for package loremipsum
    
Installing collected packages: loremipsum
  Running setup.py install for loremipsum
    
Successfully installed loremipsum
Cleaning up...
```

Proof:

```
$ python -c 'import loremipsum'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named loremipsum

$ sudo python -c 'import loremipsum'

$ pip install loremipsum
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): loremipsum in 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...

$ cowsay sad
 _____
< sad >
 -----
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Please do not advise me to use `apt-get install python-...` instead. I would like to know what is my mistake and how to use pip correctly.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$ uname -a
Linux _ 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP _ x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**EDIT**

I guess the problem is because `pip` does not allow the group and everyone to read the installed stuff:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall loremipsum
Uninstalling loremipsum:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/loremipsum-1.0.5.egg-info
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/loremipsum/__init__.py
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/loremipsum/__init__.pyc
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/loremipsum/default/dictionary.txt
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/loremipsum/default/sample.txt
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/loremipsum/generator.py
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/loremipsum/generator.pyc
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled loremipsum

$ sudo pip install loremipsum
Downloading/unpacking loremipsum
  Downloading loremipsum-1.0.5.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/loremipsum/setup.py) 
  egg_info for package loremipsum
    
Installing collected packages: loremipsum
  Running setup.py install for loremipsum
    
Successfully installed loremipsum
Cleaning up...
$ sudo ls -al /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/loremipsum
total 60
drwxr-s---  3 root staff  4096 Apr 27 22:06 .
drwxrwsr-x 18 root staff  4096 Apr 27 22:06 ..
drwxr-s---  2 root staff  4096 Apr 27 22:06 default
-rw-r-----  1 root staff 16182 Apr 27 22:06 generator.py
-rw-r-----  1 root staff 16323 Apr 27 22:06 generator.pyc
-rw-r-----  1 root staff  6130 Apr 27 22:06 __init__.py
-rw-r-----  1 root staff  6869 Apr 27 22:06 __init__.pyc
```

Comment: What is the output of `python --version` and `pip --version`?

Comment: Yes, but, I don't want to separate it from the operating system...

Comment: @wRAR  pip and virtualenv are for entirely different tasks.  It's true that many people use pip and virtualenv in combination, but I don't think it's right to say that's the *correct* use.

Comment: @wim, system packages interfere with the pip installations on *Nix systems, so yes, it is correct to say that the correct use of pip on Linux, Mac OS X, and others (such as Ubuntu, in particular) is within a virtualenv.

Comment: No it's not.  For example, if you deploy apps in docker containers you want to install to system directly.  You have no use virtualenv because isolation is provided by cgroups, and you don't have to worry about system packages changing because you deploy the containers as immutable.  This is a perfectly valid use of pip without using virtualenv.

Comment: On a docker file with pip3 not using --user option did the trick, i.e;
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You might have a wrong `umask` set as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161776/pip-inconsistent-permissions-issues)

From your last edit, I guess you `umask` is set to `027`. Try to do

```
sudo pip uninstall loremipsum
umask 022
sudo pip install loremipsum
```

Comment: For anyone interested `umask` is a command to set the default access rights for files / directories. See more [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)

Comment: Feels like a hack. Is this the official way?

Comment: @robsch no, have a look at the link of Jeremy. Check your umask with umask.

Answer (score 40):

With **Ubuntu 18.04**, using the command `sudo pip install stuff-name` does not suffice, in my case, in order to install the modules in the global path (it keeps looking at the local-user python path).

**Solution in my case**

I have changed to the *root* user, and changed directory to its home. Then `pip` installation worked like expected and installs modules in the global path.

In detail I followed the *nowox* answer with a minor change (`sudo su`, changes to the *root* user), also see final note about `umask 022`:

```
sudo su
cd ~
umask 022
pip install what-you-like
```

Note: `umask 022` command/row could be optional..., usually umask is already 022, that is the default one.

Comment: I just spent most of today trying to figure out why Flask was importable by Python on my server, except when WSGI was trying to import it. And it was because of this. Any idea why `pip` installs things in a hidden local dir now?

Comment: I don't know, sorry, I never faced this WSGI, specific, case.

Comment: @DaveTheScientist perhaps.. perhaps .. it depends on the fact that you run pip as the no-root user that is running the web server?

Comment: @FabianoTarlao no, I ran pip as a different user (that had sudo access). It looks like this behavior is standard as of Python 2.6, but it was new to me:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240037/why-did-pip-install-a-package-into-local-bin

Comment: oh yes, this is the standard behaviour, for this reason my answer used, as first step, *sudo su*, because you need to go superuser/root in order to install stuff system-globally and not in local path (also cd ~ may be useful)

Answer (score 16):

For Ubuntu 18.04 try `sudo -H pip install loremipsum`.

`-H` is the short form of `--set-home`:

```
-H, --set-home
     Request that the security policy set the HOME environment variable
     to the home directory specified by the target user's password 
     database entry.  Depending on the policy, this may be the default
     behavior.
```

In other words, this executes the `sudo` command with the HOME environment var set to root's home.

Comment: This should work for any version of Ubuntu and for any flavor of Linux.

Answer (score 11):

Use the `--target` option when calling pip

```
pip install --target=/your/pyinstalldir loremipsum
```

The target directory must be a location writable by your user.

Note that this requires the regular user environment has the target directory present in the `sys.path`. One possible way to achieve that is by using the `PYTHONPATH` env var:

```
# /etc/profile.d/myenvvars.sh
export PYTHONPATH=/your/pyinstalldir
```

Comment: To prevent erasing of previously defined variable, it's preferable to concatenate PYTHONPATH: export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/your/pyinstalldir

Answer (score 3):

## On Debian & Ubuntu 20.04

Debian, and by consequence Ubuntu, offer a `--system` option which might not be available on other GNU/Linux distributions.
Here is how to use this:

```bash
$ pip --version
    pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ pip install --help
    Install Options:
    --system    Install using the system scheme (overrides --user on Debian systems)

$ pip uninstall modulename
$ sudo pip install --system modulename
```

However, this will not work when `pip` was upgraded with `pip` from the PyPI repository:

```bash
$ pip --version
    pip 22.2.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```