# I have installed python software on ubuntu machine i want to create multiple logins on ubuntu server on AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I have Spun up Aws EC2 Ubuntu 18.0 instance I have installed python.

My requirements are.

1. I want to create multiple logins up to 50. login will happen simultaneously so VM must support multiple login
2. I want the users to login with the same `".ppkfile"` and same `public i/p` but instead of logging in as root user. `they need to login with their user names`.
3. the installed python must be accessible for all 50 users.

Is there a way that I can achieve this? Kindly suggest me on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by creating the user-account manually for each user or writing shell script to automate it. You have to follow linux `adduser` command to create users. You can also create separate keys for each user or can use password based login as well. Follow the below link to achieve the same.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html

As for the python part, if it is installed at the system level and all the users can access it. You need root access to install python at system level. This is a duplicate question and has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898474/how-to-install-a-module-for-all-users-with-pip-on-linux)

Comment: if i want 50 people to work simultaneously what would you suggest the Ram capacity of EC2 instance. what would you suggest me Please let me know

Comment: That depends on the usage of each user. Well this is not preferred solution at all as you're creating single point of failure for 50 people. AWS Workspaces might be a good solution